# wcf windows service recovery program

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a windows service hosting a WCF server.
I used "sc config...." and "sc failure..." to set the following properties:
1) log on credentials - local user
2) recovery - restart the service for the first 2 failures, and then run a program (.bat or .cmd)

I tried to test it with several ways of crashing the service, but non of them kicked in the recovery.
I tried via task manager, taskkil, throwing exception within the code, divide by zero...

and nothing happend - not the restart nor the run a program. 
Any ideas?

Comment: To make a service kill itself use `Environment.Exit(1);`

Comment: Thanks Tom, I tried that (during service starts and after I sent it a request) and on both it does fail and crash but no recovery is kicked. I tried it when I use "Local System Account" and user account, and the program is in specific folder and in "system32" folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that wcf service is spawned out in a thread from the containing service and the main thread is not exiting for child thrown exceptions as you are expecting.

[See this article.](https://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/using-the-automatic-recovery-features-of-windows-services/)

> Since this exception is being thrown on a different thread than the
>   main thread, I need to subscribe to the AppDomain’s UnhandledException
>   event. If I don’t do this the thread will just die silently and the
>   service will continue to run, which is not what I want.

Comment: Thanks Ross, this solved the problem - I can restart my service but still can't run a program.
I try to run a .bat and a .cmd files, I saw I should use forcedos.exe and the file as a parameter - but non of these works.

Comment: Are you creating your own service application and instantiating the wfc host?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work but I still confronting an issue - when my script delete a file, I see it. But when I start cmd.exe (for example), I see it in task manager but not on the screen.

Comment: That cmd dos window will wait for user input unless you tell it to. If you add a PAUSE command at the end of the cmd script the dos window will stay on screen until you dismiss it.